# Trying to create event in google calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

i was started working on google calendar recently. i gone through their documentation but it was not clear.

The code following is to insert event into users calendar.

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Google/Client.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Google/Service/Analytics.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/Google/Service/Calendar.php';

$scriptUri = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online'); 
$client->setApplicationName('MYAPP');
$client->setClientId('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // API key

$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');
$client->setScopes($scopes);
$cal = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { 
   $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
   $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
   $token = $_SESSION['token'];
   $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

header("Location: ".$authUrl);
die;
}


$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Halloween');
$event->setLocation('The Neighbourhood');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2012-10-31T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2012-10-31T10:25:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);

$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert("xxxxxx@gmail.com", $event); //Returns array not an object

echo $createdEvent->id;
```

But am getting fatal error like

```
   Class 'Google_Event' not found
```

Please help with this issue. i searched in Stack overflow for the same problem . i didn't get any solution. any type of help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for myself.

It turns out that they changed all the names again.

Replace Google by Google_Service_Calendar_

Eg:
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();

becomes now :

```
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
```

It will work !

Comment: Thanks for that solution...after changing that i resolved the Class 'Google_Event' not found  error.. But now am getting error like                             Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.' in /home2/svtemple/public_html/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:222

Comment: can you please provide any code / guidance to insert event using service account method atleast.. when am using service account also am getting errors..

Answer (score 0):

I have no working code as I opted for the Service Account method.

Maybe you can try removing the

```
 "  $client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); " which often gives error.
```

You can also modify your config.php file and opt for offline mode. (see documentation).

Finally you can refresh token with this code  :
     if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

```
 $client->authenticate();
 $NewAccessToken = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
 $client->refreshToken($NewAccessToken->refresh_token);

 }
```

Finally, you can logout, delete cache so that you get a new token. Hope it helps